# Добавить ключ => значене во вложенный массив

Tags: php, массивы

Помогите пожалуйста. Замучался уже, не могу решить задачу! 
Есть массив такого вида

```
array:2 [▼
      0 => array:4 [▼
        "id" => 1
        "name" => "Родитель"
        "parentId" => 0
        "children" => array:2 [▼
          0 => array:2 [▼
            "id" => 3
            "name" => "Ребенок1"
          ]
          1 => array:2 [▼
            "id" => 2
            "name" => "Ребенок2"
          ]
        ]
      ]
      1 => array:4 [▶]
    ]
```

Задача состоит в том что бы для каждого массива "children", во всех массивах где isset($item['children']), добавить помимо id и name, еще одну связь ключ значение. К примеру пусть будет name_en.

В итоге должен получится такой результат.

```
array:2 [▼
      0 => array:4 [▼
        "id" => 1
        "name" => "Родитель"
        "parentId" => 0
        "children" => array:2 [▼
          0 => array:2 [▼
            "id" => 3
            "name" => "Ребенок1"
            "name_en" => "Child1"
          ]
          1 => array:2 [▼
            "id" => 2
            "name" => "Ребенок2"
            "name_en" => "Child2"
          ]
        ]
      ]
      1 => array:4 [▶]
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($array as $key => $item) {
    if (isset($item['children'])) {
        $array[$key]['children']['name_en'] = //ваше значение
    } 
}
```

Comment: название children как бы намекает нам на неограниченную вложенность

Comment: И как это понять ?

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, проблема в том что в итоге результат выглядит так

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "Родитель"
    "parentId" => 0
    "children" => array:3 [▼
      0 => array:2 [▼
        "id" => 3
        "name" => "Ребенок1"
      ]
      1 => array:2 [▼
        "id" => 2
        "name" => "Ребенок2"
      ]
      "name_en" => "Child"
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▶]
]
```

То бишь он пихает его поверх children